# Change class of module joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a menu in joomla ...

In my template I show the menu like this

```
<jdoc:include type="modules"  name="header" style="none"/>
```

When I see the html generated, the class of my menu is "munu"

How change this class for other?

No put a suffix, I want change class="menu" for class="other"

Comment: you can add class from admin panel in the menu manager

Comment: Hello @Pramod How do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your **menu class** then you have to change it in the `default.php` file in `mod_menu` inside `tmpl` folder.But I am not suggest you to change the core files, To do this you can use template overridden method.For more information how to use it go through this link.

[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the suffix of the class by admin panel, you just have to go the admin panel then module manager then your menu module. in menu module you will have advanced parameter to set the class suffix as shown in the screenshot.[image]

You can change the style of the div container in case you are not able to change the menu class.

```
<div class="other"><jdoc:include type="modules"  name="header" style="xhtml"/></div> and then you can change the style with the reference of the container class.
```

Comment: Hi again @Pramod  I dont want a change a suffix I want change this  <ul class="menu pull-right">
<li></li><li></li> in my ul only the word menu... It is posible?

Comment: Can you please share the url so i can see what you actually tring to do by changing the class.

Comment: I have my proyect in local I only try to change de style

Answer (score 0):

@user852610 Override module menu html.

1. Copy module menu, paste into /templates/yourtemplate/html
2. Copy all file in tmpl folder to parent folder and remove others
3. Find and replace class "menu" in default.php